# Determine the value of register

Tags: mips

So I have a "little-endian" MIPS program:

```
    .data        
arr:    .word 12, -2, 45, 0, 0
    .text
la  $8,arr
lb  $9,2($8)
lbu $10,4($8)
sw  $10,12($8)
lb  $11,12($8)
```

The question is to determine the value of `$10` and `$11`. The answers are 254 and -2 but I don't know why. So could you explain it to me? Thanks (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: It may help if you were to say what you think they should be, and why. That way, we'll have a better idea of what exactly you're having trouble with and can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, the most important thing to note is that there are two "load byte" instructions:

1. `lbu` [the *unsigned* form] which loads a byte into the lower 8 bits of a register and "zero extends" (fills the remaining bytes with zero)
2. `lb` [the *signed* form] which loads a byte into the lower 8 bits of a register and "sign extends" (fills the remaining bytes with the most significant bit of the loaded byte) (i.e.) `fill_byte = (fetch_byte & 0x80) ? 0xFF : 0x00`

---

Here is an expanded view of the data array. All data lines are the same values, but have a different perspective. Note that after converting to a hex *word*, the hex *byte* pattern is little endian, so the bytes are in reverse order. So, when doing byte operations, we should reference the *byte* line and apply whatever offset we need:

```
offset  0               4               8               12          16
dec     12              -2              45              0           0
hexw    0000000C        FFFFFFFE        0000002D        00000000    00000000
byte    0C,00,00,00     FE,FF,FF,FF     2D,00,00,00     00,00,00,00 00,00,00,00
```

---

Here is the first program step:

```
    la      $8,arr                  # get address of array
```

---

Here is the second step:

```
    lb      $9,2($8)                # get signed byte (00) -- ignored
    lbu     $10,4($8)               # get unsigned byte (FE) and zero extend
```

After this, `$10` has `0x000000FE`, which is `254` in decimal

---

Here is the third step:

```
    sw      $10,12($8)              # store into cell
```

Now, the data array has been changed [at offset 12]:

```
offset  0               4               8               12          16
dec     12              -2              45              254         0
hexw    0000000C        FFFFFFFE        0000002D        000000FE    00000000
byte    0C,00,00,00     FE,FF,FF,FF     2D,00,00,00     FE,00,00,00 00,00,00,00
```

---

Here is the last step:

```
    # get byte from cell (FE)
    # sign extend it: FE --> FFFFFFFE
    # FFFFFFFE is -2
    lb      $11,12($8)              # get byte and _sign_ extend it
```

Remember the description for `lb` above